# How can i create a new zend Form attribute

Tags: forms, zend-framework

How can i add a new personalized attribute with zend From, exemple `<input type='text' **ref='name**' name='id_commande' id='commande'/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttrib on element for single, or setAttribs for multiple attributes you want to add

This should make a job:

```
$id_commande = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('id_commande');
$id_commande->setAttribs([
    'ref' => 'name',
    'class' => 'your_class',
    'style' => 'width: 150px'
]);
```